# Ruby on Rails, AJAX examles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'd like to know what people think what websites are good examples of AJAX with Ruby on Rails at the moment.

I'm learning both and would like to see some good interesting examples of what can be done.

THanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://haystack.com/
http://rubyonrails.org/applications

These links will open a new horizon for you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps grab a copy of http://www.redmine.org/ and look it over. Maybe not the bleeding edge of ajax but there is some good stuff in there all around for rails development. I learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just getting started and interested in unobtrusive AJAX with jQuery, I have a blog post you might be interested in. Basically it takes a simple scaffold generated site and adds unobtrusive deleting with jQuery step by step - if that sounds like something you'd be interested in feel free to [check it out](http://gaskell.org/unobtrusive-deleting-with-rails-and-jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter.com](http://twitter.com) is an excellent example of what can be done with AJAX. I believe the site is coded in Ruby on Rails as well.